# Auto select options in a <select> based on an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-select

I'm working on a project and there is a point which gives me some troubles.

I have a select form autofilled by a script. My select looks up to an array and add the array's values in the select as options.

But now I want to auto select options according to an array. 
So I have my array which has some option name inside. Each index correspond to an option. So I would like to select options corresponding to one of the value in the array.

Here is some code :

```js
var attributeFieldCrm = window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute(fieldcrm);
var checkFieldCrmValue = attributeFieldCrm.getValue();
if (checkFieldCrmValue != null) {
  console.log('breakpont hit !!!');
    var optionSelected = new Array(); 
    optionSelected = checkFieldCrmValue.split("$#");
    console.log('les valeurs ont bien été récupérées : ', optionSelected);
    var recceuilDesSelections = "";

    var result = [];
    var options = select && select.options;
    var opt;

    for (i in optionSelected) {

    }
```

```html
<select id="selectForm" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
</select>
```

I imagined something like 2 loop for, one going thought the array and for each index I check every options.

thanks for your help !

regards.

Comment: Your snippet is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you didn't provide working code, but still:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('selectForm');
optionSelected.forEach((o)=>{
  for (var i = 0;i < sel.options.length;i++) {
    if (o == sel.options[i].value) sel.options[i].selected = true;
  }
)}
```

Comment: Thank you Michal for your answer. I know my code doesn't work because I make it run an some special conditions but basicly it's just an array() and a <select> and options are selected according to the array.                           I have a problem with your code, the asside ")" doesn't seem correct for sublimeText. I'll move it and try it.